# trying to install opencv-python on Raspberry Pi, import throws: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, facial-identification

PS: I'm still new to coding on a Pi and at the moment I'm coding using putty on a laptop and jupyter notebook.

I'm trying to create a basic facial recognition software but every step keep running into errors.

I'm using the example code: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py but whenever I run their example code with my face I get the import error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 import face_recognition
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import numpy as np
      5 # Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)

ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
```

I've tried upgrading my cv2 install, and have looked around a little for other fixes but it's much easier just asking.

Comment: exact steps you took to install the package?

Comment: i tried `pip install opencv-python` a couple of times but due to it taking 2 hours to install had to cancel it a few times, but in the end finished the download.

Comment: @splatters_ Having the same issue, did you ever fix it?